# How can I pattern-match items pulled from a DashMap?

Tags: dictionary, rust

I am trying to pattern match on an `enum` when getting an item from my `dashmap::DashMap`.  However, it looks like they have a wrapper type over the `Entity` when they return the data.  How can I pattern match over the items then?

```rust
use once_cell::sync::Lazy;
use dashmap::DashMap;

enum Entity {
    Person { name: String },
    Animal { name: String },
}

static ENTITIES: Lazy<DashMap<usize, Entity>> = Lazy::new(|| DashMap::new());

fn main() {
    ENTITIES.insert(
        0,
        Entity::Animal {
            name: "pikachu".into(),
        },
    );
    ENTITIES.insert(
        1,
        Entity::Person {
            name: "trainer mike".into(),
        },
    );

    match ENTITIES.get(&0) {
        Some(Entity::Animal { name }) => { // compile error here
            println!("found animal: {}", name);
        }
        _ => panic!("did not find person"),
    }
}
```

And the error:

```rust
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src\lib.rs:__:__
   |
   |     match ENTITIES.get(&0) {
   |           -------------- this expression has type `Option<dashmap::mapref::one::Ref<'_, usize, Entity>>`
   |         Some(Entity::Animal { name }) => {
   |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `dashmap::mapref::one::Ref`, found enum `Entity`
   |
   = note: expected struct `dashmap::mapref::one::Ref<'_, usize, Entity, >`
                found enum `Entity`
```

Comment: [`ENTITIES.get(&0).map(Ref::value)`](https://docs.rs/dashmap/4.0.2/dashmap/mapref/one/struct.Ref.html#method.value)

Comment: better [`ENTITIES.get(&0).as_deref()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_deref)

Comment: Thanks @Stargateur I had to create a let binding for the `ENTITIES.get(&0)` but your solution worked after that.